# Visual Studio 2010 and XNA game studio crashes while debugging code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, xna

Now, this is a problem I've been having for a while now. I've tried googling it, asking people I know, and have searched this site for ages, but have not been able to find a solution.

I am running XNA Game Studio 4.0 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. While trying some of the basic tutorials with XNA (Available on the Microsoft website), I encountered several errors:

First off, I had set up a basic Kernel32.dll console, to calculate and display FPS. For some odd reason, after a seemingly random amount of time had elapsed it started updating the FPS several times a second. As the program ran fine, I presumed it was an error with my code, and so removed it.

But, when I did this, the program just seemed to crash. The only code in the program so far is simple draw calls, basic movement, and the foundations of a rudimentary inventory system. There is no complex code happening. I have tried several things, including placing break points on every line of code and spending hours attempting to sort this out.

So, my question is: Is this an entirely random occurrence, or is it most likely a problem with my code? And more importantly, is there a way to prevent such a bug from happening?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Code:
http://pastebin.com/3sRiVnwe

Comment: There's no link to your code, but it's better to put a minimal example that creates the behaviour you speak of in your post. This will improve your chances of getting help.

Comment: Can you also link to the tutorials you're referring to?

Comment: I decided to put the code into the page here, for ease of access. As for the tutorials, they are located at:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198548(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx

Comment: Also, on the minimal example note, I literally have no clue what causes this, so right now I am looking for anything that might be wrong and not finding anything.